# Asymptotic behavior of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have a function $f(x)$ which I know behaves like $\alpha \sqrt{x} + \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{x}} $ for large $x$. I want to extend $f(x)$ to $f(x + i y) = f(z)$, and I was hoping that the asymptotic behavior would just be $\alpha \sqrt{z} + \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{z}} $, but it isn't. I don't really understand why that is, because the way I found the asymptotic behavior of $f(x)$ was to just consider large $x$ and sort of chip away terms until those two were left. I could write the complex parameter as $z=r e^{i \theta}$, so I would have thought that considering large $x$ was the same as considering large $r$. The only other way I can think of doing this would be to explicitly write out the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)$ and then find the asymptotic behavior of each of them. I sort of started doing that, but it's turning into a nightmare so I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, or if it actually should just be $\alpha \sqrt{z} + \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{z}} $ and my numerical tests are wrong.

Comment: Have you heard of Stokes' Phenomenon?  For example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_line

Comment: @RonGordon I hadn't heard of that, but that sounds like something to look at. It doesn't really say how to find a Stokes line but I'm sure it's mentioned somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, the behaviour of a function of a complex variable is rather difficult to judge from just its behaviour for real values. For example, if you just look at real values, the function $f(x) = \sin x$ is nicely bounded and just oscillates between $-1$ and $+1$, but when you consider $f(z) = \sin z$ as a function of a complex variable it is unbounded. I would suspect that your numerical tests are not wrong, but the complex function might just be more ... complex :)

Comment: Well said, Old John.  I believe there is an entire body of theorems addressing the behavior of holomorphic functions, which we could skip if we could just pretend R is the story.  Actually, the story is somewhat the other way around; if we know what's going on with the complex function, we might learn something about it as a real function.

Comment: "The shortest path between two truths in the real domain passes through the complex domain" - Jacques Hadamard (1865-1963)

Comment: @OldJohn True, so you're saying I should do the real and imaginary parts thing?

Comment: I suspect that might be necessary, unfortunately - but I am still thinking about the problem ...

Comment: Why not post what the actual function is?  Hard to say anything otherwise.

Comment: @AntonioVargas This is tangentially related to original research so I don't really want "the" answer I guess. I was more just hoping that people would say that finding the asymptotic behavior of a complex function is a known problem, read this textbook etc.

Comment: There are certainly some good books on asymptotic analysis in general, and the methods usually depend on how the function is defined (if it's an integral, an infinite sum, an algebraic function, a solution to a differential equation, etc.).  I like de Bruijn's Asymptotic Methods in Analysis and Miller's Applied Asymptotic Analysis.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Okay thanks, I'll check those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function extends to any simply connected domain in $\mathbb C$, which misses the origin. For example, the most typical such domain is $\mathbb C\smallsetminus(-\infty,0]$. You can not thus talk about the behaviour of this function, as $z\to\infty$, because this function can not be defined in any domain which contain a whole neighborhood of $\infty$!

Comment: Is the part about missing the origin only there because there's a $1/\sqrt{x}$ term? That term 'doesn't exist' for small $x$. Like, near the origin, $f(x)$ behaves linearly.

Comment: The origin can not be an element of the domain where the extension of $f$ is defined because of the appearance of the $\sqrt{x}$. Even if $f$ extend to a Riemann surface (roots extend to Riemann surfaces), still zero has to be missing.

Comment: I see. So if the asymptotic behavior of $f(x)$ was something simpler like $x$, then there wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: It should be made clear what "this function" means here: it is the function $\alpha\sqrt{x}+\beta/\sqrt{x}$ itself, not the (classified) function $f$ in the question. To @Mr.G If the asymptotic behavior was something like $x$, there would be the same problem: nobody can tell you what the asymptotic of $f$ is in the complex plane just by looking at its asymptotics on the real line. Examples were already given in comments, here is one more: add $e^{-x^2}$ to the function: it is very tiny on the real line, and huge in the complex plane.

Comment: @PostNoBills Okay, thanks.